# Bower, Grunt & zsh: command not found:

Tags: twitter, zsh, npm, gruntjs

I have installed Grunt & Bower & I'm using ZSH.

when I type `bower --help` or `grunt anything` I get `zsh: command not found: bower` or `zsh: command not found: grunt` how can I fix this?

Comment: What did you do to install? `npm install -g grunt`? `npm install -g grunt-cli` ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` to your `$PATH environment`

Comment: For those using a ZSH shell, add this to .zshrc: "export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

Comment: @ Sam & neon ... 
I had same issue while trying use bower plugin for zsh, and now it's solved. Thanks dudes ;)

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't get the above to work. Problem was that I had just reinstalled my Mac and forgotten to re-install grunt.

You can test that grunt is actually installed and working properly outside of zshell by going back to bash with `bash -l` and running `grunt`.

If grunt is throwing the same error you can install grunt by running:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Run `zsh` to get back to zshell.

Answer (score 8):

When you installed, did you install globally?

```
npm install -g bower
```

give that a try. If not, also try adding sudo

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: I installed it using the command on their website `npm install bower -g`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with ```vows``` here =/

Answer (score 2):

When you install grunt (bower), terminal tell you directory. For those using a ZSH shell, add this to .zshrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/you/directory/npm/bin:$PATH,
```

I find it using:

```
/lib/node_modules
export PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `yarn` instead of `npm`:

```
yarn add grunt grunt-cli
yarn grunt
```

It worked for me.
Hopefully, it will help someone else :)

Comment: Hooray for yarn! Easy peasy! 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GNOME-Terminal (default in Ubuntu Unity and Gnome) try the answer of https://askubuntu.com/questions/279180/nvm-command-not-found-issue.