# Solutions to solve "zsh: command not found: grunt" not working

Tags: gruntjs, zsh

Trying to run `grunt` in my command line, but I am getting `zsh: command not found: grunt`.

In my project directory, I ran `npm install -g grunt-cli`, as per the grunt [documentation](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started). I've tried running `npm install` and `npm install grunt --save-dev`. I still get the same result.

Options I've tried:

- adding grunt to zsh as a plugin
- adding `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` to `$PATH`, as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555129/bower-grunt-zsh-command-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- the solutions in [this article](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grunt-command-not-found/) on Hongkiat ("Solving Grunt “Command Not Found” Error in Terminal [Quickfix]"). There is a command here that is deprecated.
- trying `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

None of these are working. Any tips on how to get grunt to work?

My system:

- Mac OS v10.11
- npm v5.6.0
- node v8.9.4
- zsh 5.0.8

Comment: Did you install `grunt` globally? Otherwise I would not expect it to appear in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`. Did you also check out the other answers in [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555129/bower-grunt-zsh-command-not-found)?

Comment: @Adaephon Yes, I updated the question to include this information.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a .zshrc file and other files necessary to set the zsh paths on your mac?

Comment: While this may be a rhetorical question, can you rephrase that to sound more like an answer and less like a question?

Comment: Pease don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer.